# media queries with bootstrap not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I wanted to have large pictures be hidden for mobile devices. Looking [at this site](http://ageekandhisblog.com/css-how-to-easily-hide-content-on-only-mobile-or-only-desktop/) I put the following styles in my css:

```
//medium+ screen sizes
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .desktop {
            display:block !important;
    }
}

//small screen sizes
@media (max-width:991px) {
    .mobile {
            display:block !important;
    }

    .desktop {
            display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Then I apply the class in my html like this:

```
<img class="desktop" src="img/test/test.jpg" 
    alt="jhkjhjk" height="600" width="900">
```

But when I shrink my browser window the image remains there. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Boostrap, you can do it even easier.

Append a class of

```
visible-md
```

to your image.

md is for >992 px.

Check out the easy classes you can use
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

EDIT: probably wanna do visible-md visible-lg if you're gonna do visibles. The chart explains all the combinations.

Comment: Awesome, that's even better I'll just do that. Still though why weren't my media queries working?

Comment: I'm not the best with media queries, but you might need to specify the media tpye "@media screen"